# Extract files from tgz to tar and from tar to txt Databricks Python3 Unix/Linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, shell, apache-spark, databricks

I have many files in tgz format which contain tar files, and the tar files them self contain txt files.
I want to extract them 1st to tar and then to txt format(or immediately to txt if that is possible, that is even better) using python(3.x if possible) in Databricks.

I have tried

```
tar = tarfile.open('/dbfs/mnt/mountingPoint/InputFolder/filename.tgz', 'r:gz')
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
```

but even though it doesn't give any errors, I don't get any files.
I went through all the existing posts regarding the topic but those weren't helpful.

I also tried:

```
%sh find $/dbfs/mnt/mountingPoint/InputFolder/ -name *.tar.gz -exec tar -xvzf {} -C $/dbfs/mnt/mountingPoint/OututFolder/ \;
```

and I get the following error:

```
find: ‘$/dbfs/mnt/mountingPoint/InputFolder/’: No such file or directory
```

I don't have much experience with Unix/Linux so probably there is a silly error in there, because the file and the directory are for sure there.

I have done a lot of research but none of them matches my use case. Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: are you working on the Community Edition? And what DBR version are you using?

Comment: I am working on the Standard Edition and the DBR is 7.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I added an output folder to tar.extractall() and now it works.**

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open('/dbfs/mnt/mountingPoint/InputFolder/filename.tgz', 'r:gz')
tar.extractall('/dbfs/mnt/mountingPoint/OutputFolder/')
tar.close()
```

**If you want to have the files extracted one by one, another solution would be:**

```
for member in tar.getmembers():
   extracted_f = tar.extract(member, '/dbfs/mnt/mountingPoint/OutputFolder/')
```

**But still, if anyone has a solution for the shell section, I would love to know.**